# How to debug a Java UnsatisfiedLinkError?

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

On Windows (everything works on OSX), I have a Java library which depends on a native library. I load this individual library with `System.load()`, and right after an `UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't find dependent libraries` exception shows up.

The native library has no particular dependencies – it only relies on system libraries, as confirmed by dependency walker (where it's perfectly ok). I have tried using a x86 version with an x86 JRE and an x64 version with an x64 JRE, having faced no change at all.

After spending two days after this, I would like to know if there is more information that can be obtained from this exception: **what** library is it trying to load, for instance?

Comment: What's your windows version and C/C++ compiler? Maybe it's `platform toolset` problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using `System.load()` on an arbitrary file name. For it to work, it apparently requires the explicit extension `.dll`.

Comment: No 'apparently' about it. It says so in the Javadoc: 'The filename argument must be a complete path name.'

Comment: The file did not have any extension -- and it *was* being loaded with the complete path name. The error only stopped when the file got `.dll` as its extension,